# Formula to Dynamically Stack Columns with Spill Down

Tags: excel-formula

For **EXCEL 365**

I am looking for a formula that will dynamically stack the contents of two columns, one on top of the other.  For example, if I start with:

[image]

I want the formula to produce:

[image]

I can achieve this with "semi-dynamic":

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNTA(A:A)+COUNTA(C:C),"",IF(ROWS($1:1)<COUNTA(A:A)+1,INDEX(A:A,ROWS($1:1)),INDEX(C:C,ROWS($1:1)-COUNTA(A:A))))
```

It just `INDEXs` down the first column until all items are retrieved and then `INDEXs` down the second column.

1. it is dynamic in the sense that the output adjusts to adding/removing items from columns **A** or **B**
2. it is manual in the sense that it must be manually copied downward rather than spill down by itself

I can get the desired behavior with VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function stack2(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Variant
    Dim c1 As Long, c2 As Long, r As Range, temp
    Dim i As Long
    
    c1 = r1.Count
    c2 = r2.Count
    ReDim temp(1 To c1 + c2, 1 To 1)
    i = 1
    
    For Each r In r1
        temp(i, 1) = r.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next r
    For Each r In r2
        temp(i, 1) = r.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next r
    
    stack2 = temp
End Function
```

But I need a formula rather than VBA.  I can retrieve and spill-down a single column with:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)))
```

But I can't figure out how to handle two columns.

Any ideas??

Comment: does order matter?

Comment: @ScottCraner Order is not important.... **A1,C1,A2,C2** is Okay

Comment: is B to be skipped on purpose or will it be blank or does it get included if there is data?

Comment: see if any of these answer your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204826/excel-unique-across-columns/62903013#62903013

Comment: Both answers work just fine!   I just discard the `SORT()` and `UNIQUE()` it handles leaving column **B** blank as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the `ROWS($1:1)` with `SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)+COUNTA(C:C))`

```
=IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)+COUNTA(C:C))<COUNTA(A:A)+1,INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)+COUNTA(C:C))),INDEX(C:C,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)+COUNTA(C:C))-COUNTA(A:A)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!