# How to merge two vertical number lists into one long vertical list in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

So I have a few columns with numbers and I'm wondering how to make a dynamic combined list of them all? I know consolidate could theoretically work but my lists change and I don't think consolidating is dynamic. The 'Combines List' on the right is what I hope to accomplish. I want all duplicates but I don't want any spaces because for example Column C could go from having 3 numbers to 5 numbers easily. Also sorting the list would be a super bonus as that's my final goal so if I can go about this another way let me know.

[image]

Comment: You could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62903013/9245853) and just remove the `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, with O365:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,TRANSPOSE(numBers)) & "</s></t>","//s")
```

If you want the list sorted, then:

```
=SORT(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,TRANSPOSE(numBers)) & "</s></t>","//s"))
```

***EDIT** If you are running on the MAC, or online Excel, you do not have the `FILTERXML` function.  You can use the following formula instead:*

```
=SORT(--TRIM(MID(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",99),TRUE,TRANSPOSE(C10:F29)),(SEQUENCE(COUNT(numBers))-1)*99+1,99)))
```

*This formula will work for a bit more than 300 or so characters (digits), after which you will run into the 32,767 character limit for `TEXTJOIN`. The first formula will have a limit of a bit more than 3,000 numbers.  If you might have more than that, you should look at a VBA solution*

`numBers` is a named range larger than what you need.  Blanks will be ignored.  In this case, I use `c10:f100`, but you can increase the size to suit.

[image]

***with sort***

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to get this formula working even on my example data. Is there some setting to toggle? I have =FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,TRANSPOSE(C10:F29)) & "</s></t>","//s")

Comment: @guanciale  What does *"can't seem to get this formula working"* mean? Wrong answer? Error message? (if so, what is it?) Excel freezes? Something else?

Comment: Oh sorry for being vague! I'm getting "#NAME?" error. I tried recreating it in the web version of Excel and also am getting the same error. Perhaps just a version issue?

Comment: @guanciale you must be running on a MAC. No `FILTERXML`. I'll provide a different version of the formula tomorrow.

Comment: @guanciale See my edit for a formula that should work on O365 for the Mac or online Excel

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Office 365, try this small User Defined Function:

```
Public Function stackum(rng As Range)
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Dim arr, i As Long, brr, b
    
    ReDim arr(1 To wf.CountA(rng), 1 To 1)
    
    brr = rng
    i = 1
    For Each b In brr
        If b <> "" Then
            arr(i, 1) = b
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next b
    
    stackum = arr
End Function
```

[image]

As you see, it spills down dynamically.

If you want a formula rather than a UDF, try:

```
=LET(z,INDEX($C$10:$F$18,MOD(SEQUENCE(4*9)-1,9)+1,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(4*9)/9,0)),FILTER(z,z<>""))
```

It also spills down.  I don't like this formula.  It relies on the "magic number" ***9*** which is the height of the input table.

**EDIT#1:**

To eliminate **both** magic numbers *(4, 9)* we can use:

```
=LET(tb,$C$10:$F$18,cl,COLUMNS(tb),rw,ROWS(tb),z,INDEX(tb,MOD(SEQUENCE(cl*rw)-1,9)+1,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(cl*rw)/rw,0)),FILTER(z,z<>""))
```

Comment: Why not add a 2nd LET entry LET(h,rows($c$10:$F$18),z,...) and use h where you currently have 9?

Comment: @DS_London Great idea...............we can also add a `Let` to remove the *4* as well.  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

Formula solution for all Excel version

1] "Combine List with sort" in `H10`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(SMALL($C$10:$F$18,ROW(A1)),"")
```

2] "Combine List with sort  & remove duplicate" in `I10`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(ROW(A1)<=SUMPRODUCT(($C$10:$F$18<>"")/COUNTIF($C$10:$F$18,$C$10:$F$18&"")),SMALL($C$10:$F$18,COUNTIF($C$10:$F$18,"<="&I9)+1),"")
```

[image]