# Is it possible to concatenate ranges with unknown lengths in excel without VBA?

Tags: excel

I have the following ranges:

| range1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

| range2 |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 4 |

How to concatenate them to get:

| range3 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

I tried "Consolidate" - but it is not what I need.

I also read this guide https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7. But didn't manage to find an answer there

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate ranges"? Trivially one can have formulas in one range that draws data from two other ranges, but you seem to be wanting some unspecified degree of automation in the process.

Comment: @JohnColeman I mean ranges of unknown lengths. Edited

Comment: @JvdV thanks, see edits

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft365 you could use:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,A:A,B:B)&"</s></t>","//s")
```

Where `A:A` is a placeholder for you 1st range and `B:B` for your 2nd range. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62205206/9758194) answer by @BigBen which shows the idea of "flattening" multiple columns although his query continues pulling unique values only.

Comment: many thanks. I work in Excel 2010 unfortunately