# How to extract unique items from multiple column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am trying to extract unique values from multiple column. Below image demonstrate my sample data and desired output. My data will increase day by day and I want to get unique list to a separate column. I have tried below formula `line feed character char(10) as separator` which gives me result in a single and I then have to manually `WRAP TEXT` the cell. But I want result to separate cells not in same cell.

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,B4:D10)
```

[image]

I have also tried `UNIQUE()` formula. But this doesn't give me desired result.

```
=UNIQUE(B4:D10)
```

[image]

Comment: I have different approach of `FILTERXML()` formula to achieve desired result.

Comment: @Harun24HR Can you please put?

Comment: I can't as it is already closed.

Comment: OP: does the linked duplicate approach using `FILTERXML`, `TEXTJOIN` and `UNIQUE` not solve your question? Or you can use the alternate approach in the same linked thread that overcomes `TEXTJOIN`s limitations.

Comment: @Harun24HR - perhaps you can add your answer to the linked thread as it can definitely use more answers.

Comment: @BigBen I will add. Basically we can directly get unique values from FILTERXML without UNIQUE function. So, answer can be used non 365 users having TEXTJOIN and FILTERXML only.

Comment: @BigBen Yes it did solve my problem. But my collogues use Office2019 and they don't have FILTER function. So, It can't use to other computer of my company.

Comment: @Harun24HR Can you post as you described in comment. It would be helpful for me if we can use to Office2019 excel users.

Comment: @RainyDay - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/9245853) and the part about returning unique values from `FILTERXML`.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for link. I will go through it.

Comment: @RainyDay I have post as answer to [linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66361639/5514747). If you wish you can have a look.

Comment: From link provided by BigBen I was trying accomplish to Excel2019 and facing few difficulties to adjust. Answer of Harun24HR make it clearer. Finally I adopt the solution to Excel2019. I had to use `Index()` function as `Excel2019` don't spill results automatically. Thanks to both of you.